# Convert Days in Array to date in a week range

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

I have days in array like this:

```
$days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Thursday','Friday','Sunday'];
```

I want to convert it into date format for a week range, for example if today's date is 28-September-2017, i want the result to look like this in an array:

```
$dateResult = ['28 Sep','29 Sep','01 Oct', '02 Oct', '03 Oct']
```

it will find the date in format like above in a week range starting from today

Comment: no Saturday? ....

Comment: 1 sep 2 sep? Or do you mean october? Also, what's the logic behind the dates in this way?

Comment: @rtfm the day in array is the available day to convert

Comment: and what have you tried to do so far? What problem are you having? You can get today's date, yes? You can find out how to parse a day name online easily enough, you can find out how to format a date as well. This isn't a free coding service, you are expected to show some research and coding effort of your own first. BTW your example doesn't make a lot of sense. Why is the first element of the array 28th Sept? It's not a monday. And why do you go back to the start of September? The first array seems to be unrelated to the second. Why does the first one ignore Saturday? It's all very unclear.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator oh yes i forgot about it, see my updated question

Comment: why is 30 sep not present here? Are we supposed to show 4 days? Except Sunday? Please explain the logic clearly.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator because 30 Sep day is not $days array value

Comment: @simpleguy so that what about wednesday?

Comment: Monday is not 28th Sept. Then how you want it, is it your sample data?

Comment: @simpleguy monday is not 28, tuesday is not 29 what u actullay need

Comment: It still makes no sense. 28th September is not a Monday, it's a Thursday. So if the $days array starts on a Monday, why should the $dateResult array start on a Monday? You haven't given any rule to specify why that should happen. Your example does not conform to the requirements that you've given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will consider 7 days from today.

```
$days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Thursday','Friday','Sunday'];

$ret = [] ;
for( $i = 0; $i < 7; $i ++) {
    $t = strtotime('+' . $i . ' day') ;
    if( in_array( Date('l', $t), $days ) ) {
        $ret[] = Date('d M', $t) ;
    }
}
print_r($ret) ;
```

Comment: sorry, did not get u

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    /* Get day name i.e Friday, Saturday etc */
    $day_name    =     date("l", strtotime("+$i day"));
    /* Store result in array only if day is present in $days */
    if (in_array($day_name, $days)) {
        $result[]    =    date("d M", strtotime("next " . $day_name, strtotime("+". $i ." day")));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
 [0] => 29 Sep
 [1] => 01 Oct
 [2] => 02 Oct
 [3] => 03 Oct
 [4] => 05 Oct
)
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to convert days to the number. example: 1 for Monday and 2 for Tuesday and so on.

```
//$days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Thursday','Friday','Sunday'];

$days_in_number = [1,2,4,5,7];

$r = array();
$today = date('N');
foreach($days_in_number as $x){
  $r[] = date('M-d',strtotime((($today-$x) * -1).' days'));
}

print_r($r);
```

Note: This code will only work for current 1 week.

Comment: sorry mate, if this does not work for you. I don't know what you are looking for.